# phpmyadmin: know the import progress of sql file

Tags: phpmyadmin

Im importing large size of sql file in PHPMyAdmin and it takes to long to import. is there any way to know its progress?.

like some kind of loading bar or percent of its progress?.

and i'm importing using the browser not the mysqldump command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort of; phpMyAdmin [does have an upload progress bar](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html#seeing-an-upload-progress-bar), but there are some additional webserver dependencies:

> To be able to see a progress bar during your uploads, your server must
>   have the [APC](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) extension [or] the [uploadprogress](https://pecl.php.net/package/uploadprogress) one
>
> ...
>
> Moreover, the JSON extension has to be enabled in
>   your PHP.
>
> If using APC, you must set `apc.rfc1867` to `on` in your `php.ini`.

As some background information, this is a bit difficult to determine; since phpMyAdmin runs on the server that means it has difficulty knowing the size of the file before the upload is completed, which makes it inaccurate to show progress. I've never gone to the trouble to configure these additional requirements, so I'm not sure how well this works in practice.

Comment: oh. that's why i can't see any solution when i search it. thanks btw.